# Change sql query to Hibernate Criteria Api

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Hi i am new to Criteria Api in Hibernate.Below is the query which i need to convert to Criteria Query..

```
select upper(first_name) from users where upper(first_name) = 'FRED';
```

I am done lots of googling to find this out,but none of them suits my needs.let me know how to do it??

Comment: where exactly are you stuck? remove the `upper()` ops and you have got yourself the second simplest query out there. Translate it to the Criteria API first and then look up the CriteriaBuilder docs for incorporating the `upper`.

Comment: @kostja: I removed the upper() ops from select query,below is my code.let me know where i need to change                       Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("firstName", “'FRED'
”));